# Submit to session without changing page?

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a webshop project with PHP and I'm having difficulties with the shopping cart.
Basically I've made a session like this:

```
session_start();
$cart = array('product1', 'product2'); //Test values
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
```

And then, when I open the page of a product, I want to have the possiblility to add the product in my array with a button.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post"><button name="buy" type="submit">
Buy It!</button></form>
```

And this is the code of submit.php: `<?php $cart[]="product3";?>`

Now that's actually not working at all. I'm using $_POST, the webpage changes, and the new product is not added to the session Array...

My question is: How can I stay in the same webpage when submitting and how can I actually add it to the session array?

Comment: http://www.php.net/array_push

Comment: I have the impression you are looking for AJAX instead.

Comment: Ajax is the best option for you

Answer (score 1):

change submit.php to

```
      <?php 
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['cart'][]="product3";
      ?>
```

to stay on same webpage .. you have to submit form using **ajax**.. learn [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)